# Play video after tracking image success with Spark Ar

Tags: spark-ar-studio

Do you know how to play video after success tracking image in Spark Ar. I see it only support audio with Audio Playback Controller. Now , i want to play video.(i don't  want to use animationSequence to make sprite sheet  animation (simulate video))
How can i do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only through `Animation Sequence`. This is the only and universal way. The engine does not support any video formats.